# problem with PHP looping through members

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with my updation script, basically if I keep the line as mysql_fetch_row then it only seems to want to insert every other member into the database, but if I change it to mysql_fetch_array then it inserts each member twice, but still not all the users from the database. I have just shown the start of the script below as I am pretty sure this must be where the error is.
Any help with this would be fantastic. Cheers.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT member_id FROM members ORDER BY member_id");

    while ($member = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        foreach ($member as &$member_id){

            $results_query = mysql_query("SELECT driver1 as driver1, driver2 as driver2, driver3 as driver3, driver4 as driver4, team as team, engine as engine, total_points as total FROM members WHERE member_id = '$member_id'")
            or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());

$userteam = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_query);

 //this is the bottom of the script after calculations have take place and the insert into the database//

 $results_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO member_results (member_id, track_id, driver1, driver2, driver3, driver4, team, engine, driver1_points, driver2_points, driver3_points, driver4_points, team_points, engine_points, qualifying_points, race_points, total_points)
            VALUES ('$member_id', '$track', '$userteam[driver1]', '$userteam[driver2]', '$userteam[driver3]', '$userteam[driver4]', '$userteam[team]', '$userteam[engine]', '$userpoints[driver1]', '$userpoints[driver2]', '$userpoints[driver3]', '$userpoints[driver4]', '$userpoints[team]', '$userpoints[engine]', '$userpoints[qualifying]', '$userpoints[race]', '$userpoints[total]')")
            or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());

            $userteam["total"] += $userpoints["total"];

            $results_query = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET total_points = '$userteam[total]' WHERE member_id = '$member_id'")
            or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());


        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no INSERT code. Please include more code (in particular the code that inserts the record).

Comment: your update query is a "SELECT ..." query

Comment: i just cant understand it!, i took away the ORDER by member_id and it inserted the first 6 members fine and then went back to inserting every other, and it will only insert 9 rows, no more then that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a foreach loop when using mysql_fetch_array. The reason your query is being entered twice is because mysql_fetch_array fetches both an associative array and a numerical array for the row data, so it's looking at both of them and inserting the data twice, one for each array.

`$member` doesn't require a foreach for this reason. $member is just one row being pulled, not the entire data set. An associative array returns the column names as array keys.

```
   while ($member = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                $results_query = mysql_query("SELECT driv1 as drivone, driv2 as drivtwo, 
driv3 as drivthree, driv4 as drivfour, team as teamone, 
eng as engone, total_points as total FROM members WHERE member_id = '$member['member_id']'") // If member_id is the column name for the ID
                or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns multiple arrays(associative array, a numeric array, or both)
thats why its inserting twicein your foreach, and could be the reason why your script is breaking.

try var_dumping $member to see what syntax you can use to refine your foreach

see documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

by default mysql_fetch_array return:

- the NUM indexation ( array( 0 => ..., 1 => ...)),
- but also merge-in the assoc indexation ( array( 'fieldname' => ... , 'colname' => ...))

So your code should look like:
** Note that've removed the foreach.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT member_id FROM members ORDER BY member_id");

    while ($member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $member_id = $member['member_id'];
        //foreach ($member as &$member_id){

            $results_query = mysql_query("SELECT driver1 as driver1, driver2 as driver2, driver3 as driver3, driver4 as driver4, team as team, engine as engine, total_points as total FROM members WHERE member_id = '$member_id'")
            or die ("Failed to update" . mysql_error());

$userteam = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_query);
//...
```

Comment: Yes, that's because your initial SELECT statement doesn't have any WHERE statement, so it select all the users. And then you use the results of this selection to do your update...

Comment: no what I mean is that it is inserting say member_id 32, then 34, then 36, then 38, where it should be updating 33,35 and 37 as well.

Comment: That second problem doesn't seem to be explainable with the code you've given in your initial message :( Double check if your ressource handler ( $result, $results_query ) are not conflicting ?

Comment: i just cant understand it!, i took away the ORDER by member_id and it inserted the first 6 members fine and then went back to inserting every other, and it will only insert 9 rows, no more then that. :(

Comment: Maybe you should re-think your whole code... sometime thing get simpler (and better) when started over ;)